# How to know the folder name or path of "Do you trust the authors of the files in this folder?"

Tags: visual-studio-code

I want to display either folder-path or folder-name that is causing this security dialog in VSCode.

- This dialog shows that "the parent folder name is `Proj`. However the name of `this folder` is hidden."
- Is it good enough info to deal with push `Yes, I trust the authors` button?

This means I'm missing something to do? otherwise this behavior is by design?

[image: Do you trust the authors of the files in this folder? figure]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK this issue has been fixed around VSCode 1.58.2.

- [Show folder in Workspace Trust dialog · Issue #125984 · microsoft/vscode](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/125984)
- [adding basic folder info to dialog · microsoft/vscode@3724cf8](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/commit/3724cf8f6e60e029904bf44e1dc5ad8d26b48d84)

Now I can confirm the target folder path in dialog:

[image: Do you trust the authors of the files in this folder?]